# Edit search results template in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, loops, search

I have created a page template with a nice layout using the lovely custom fields plugin so my client can easily update the content.

I created a loop on that page template that displays the relevant information nicely;

Here is the loop I made:

```
        <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cripps_staff', 'posts_per_page' => 300 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    echo '<div class="col-md-3 spacetop">';
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'image',true);
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffname">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_name',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffrole">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_role',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffnumber">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_telephone_number',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<h2 class="staffemail">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'staff_email_address',true);
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

I created taxonomies so the staff members are split into categories.

I am then using a plugin called Taxonomies filter to create those dropdown options you will see. When you select an element in the dropdowns, Wordpress goes to/changes the page to a custom search results page I created. I want my search results to be displayed exactly like my loop on the People's template. Currently it just spits it out the title in a h1 tag.

Here is the code I got from the Twenty Fourteen theme:

```
                <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                CrippsTheme_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>
```

How can I get the search results to look exactly like my Post loop?

Comment: Here's a handy guide on the WordPress codex which might help you out https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: Hi @JPiiONEFOURONE I already looked at that guide, it shows how to add static content to search results page, not how to edit the dynamic loop in the way I need it to display, but thanks for trying though.

Comment: @ArchieButler could you post your current code that you are usign that doesnt work the one that 'Currently it just spits it out the title in a h1 tag.'

Comment: @ArchieButler I have just taken a look at content.php in the twentyfourteen theme and found where is it outputting the h1 if that is of any use to you? line 27 `the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );`

Comment: Because I am using a custom post type and custom taxanomies, the search results get outputted in the default content-page.php template. In order to have a custom layout for my search results I changed the search results query from "get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );" to "get_template_part( 'content', 'peopleformat' ); ," (using help form the link below in my answer), I then duplicated content-page.php and renamed it content-peopleformat.php to catch the wordpress hook. In there I added the results layout I wanted, I put the code of content-peopleformat.php below. @JPiiONEFOURONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this completely with the help of Pieter Goosen, who provided me with an awesomely detailed response, see the full answer on Wordpress development forum:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143023/edit-wordpress-loop-taxonomies-filter